# Creating a multiple dimension array from 2 existing one

Tags: php

I am dealing with some mismatch data when working with 2 separate dimensional array.

So I have the first array `$distinctAssg`:

```
Array (4)
0 => "passport"
1 => "certificates"
2 => "degrees"
3 => "bla bal"
```

And the second one $group_assgn

```
Array (2)
test tert => Array (3)
  passport => Array (6)
    id => "1"
    assgn => "passport"
    status => "passed"
    name => "test"
    surname => "tert"
    branches_ID => "1"
  certificates => Array (6)
    id => "2"
    assgn => "certificates"
    status => "started"
    name => "test"
    surname => "tert"
    branches_ID => "1"
  bla bal => Array (6)
    id => "4"
    assgn => "bla bal"
    status => "started"
    name => "test"
    surname => "tert"
    branches_ID => "1"
john doe => Array (3)
  passport => Array (6)
    id => "1"
    assgn => "passport"
    status => "started"
    name => "john"
    surname => "doe"
    branches_ID => "1"
  certificates => Array (6)
    id => "2"
    assgn => "certificates"
    status => "passed"
    name => "john"
    surname => "doe"
    branches_ID => "1"
  degrees => Array (6)
    id => "3"
    assgn => "degrees"
    status => "completed"
    name => "john"
    surname => "doe"
    branches_ID => "1"
```

since user can have or not assignments depending on what they have completed i want to build a array to create a table but i need the data to be in the correct order. Why do I have mismatch because the degree is coming up in the end as empty. I want to have the same order as distinctAssg.

Here is my code:

```
$response = array();
        foreach ($distinctAssg as $value)
        {
            foreach ($group_assgn as $key => $user_asg)
            {
                var_dump($user_asg);
                if(in_array($value, array_column($user_asg, 'assgn')))
                {
                    if (!array_key_exists($value, $response[$key])) {
                        $response[$key] = $user_asg;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (!array_key_exists($value, $response[$key])) {
                        $response[$key][$value] = array('status' => 'empty');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and here is what i get.

```
Array (2)
test tert=> Array (4)
  passport => Array (6)
    id => "1"
    assgn => "passport"
    status => "passed"
    name => "test"
    surname => "tert"
    branches_ID => "1"
  certificates => Array (6)
    id => "2"
    assgn => "certificates"
    status => "started"
    name => "test"
    surname => "tert"
    branches_ID => "1"
  bla bal => Array (6)
    id => "4"
    assgn => "bla bal"
    status => "started"
    name => "test"
    surname => "tert"
    branches_ID => "1"
  degrees => Array (1)
    status => "empty"
john doe => Array (4)
  passport => Array (6)
    id => "1"
    assgn => "passport"
    status => "started"
    name => "john"
    surname => "doe"
    branches_ID => "1"
  certificates => Array (6)
    id => "2"
    assgn => "certificates"
    status => "passed"
    name => "john"
    surname => "doe"
    branches_ID => "1"
  degrees => Array (6)
    id => "3"
    assgn => "degrees"
    status => "completed"
    name => "john"
    surname => "doe"
    branches_ID => "1"
  bla bal => Array (1)
    status => "empty"
```

how can i have the same order because if dont exist i add it as empty

Comment: are you looking for [sort()](http://php.net/sort) (or a related function)?

Comment: well i am very confused that why does the degree come up as latest in the response array because as order it should be before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, working solution [here](https://tehplayground.com/XvKNOWbcu2NKWcWn). Please next time post proper arrays instead of `vardump` or `print_r` results.

```
$keys = ["passport", "certificates", "degrees", "bla bal"];

$dataArr = [
    "test tert" => [
        "passport" => [
            "id" => "1",
            "assgn" => "passport",
            "status" => "passed",
            "name" => "test",
            "surname" => "tert",
            "branches_ID" => "1",
        ],
        "certificates" => [
            "id" => "2",
            "assgn" => "certificates",
            "status" => "started",
            "name" => "test",
            "surname" => "tert",
            "branches_ID" => "1",
        ],
        "bla bal" => [
            "id" => "4",
            "assgn" => "bla bal",
            "status" => "started",
            "name" => "test",
            "surname" => "tert",
            "branches_ID" => "1",
        ]
    ],
    "john doe" => [
        "passport" => [
            "id" => "1",
            "assgn" => "passport",
            "status" => "passed",
            "name" => "test",
            "surname" => "tert",
            "branches_ID" => "1",
        ],
        "certificates" => [
            "id" => "2",
            "assgn" => "certificates",
            "status" => "started",
            "name" => "test",
            "surname" => "tert",
            "branches_ID" => "1",
        ],
        "degrees" => [
            "id" => "3",
            "assgn" => "degrees",
            "status" => "completed",
            "name" => "john",
            "surname" => "doe",
            "branches_ID" => "1",
        ],
    ],
];


$res = [];
foreach($dataArr as $key=>$val){
    $obj_keys = array_keys($val);
    foreach($keys as $k){
        $res[$key][$k] = in_array($k, $obj_keys)?$val[$k]:[];
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked perfectly.
And sorry for the var_dumps

Comment: cant up vote because of my reputation. Just opened this account.

Comment: @Elio in the future you can use [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) instead, which will produce a PHP array.